# Iterate entity properties and count not null values

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to count how many fields in entity are not null. Specifically, if the property is ArrayCollection, identify if collection is not empty.

Here I am getting all User object properties

```
   $properties = $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:User')->getFieldNames();
   $output = array_merge(
        $properties,
        $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:User')->getAssociationNames()
    );

   foreach($output as $property){
          ????
   }
```

Question how to loop through entity properties and count not null or not empty properties.

`var_dump($output)` outputs:

```
array (size=47)
  0 => string 'username' (length=8)
  1 => string 'usernameCanonical' (length=17)
  2 => string 'email' (length=5)
  3 => string 'emailCanonical' (length=14)
  ... 
  45 => string 'expertise' (length=13) // ManyToOne association
  46 => string 'reports' (length=7) // OneToMany association. type ArrayCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an entity object to pass it to the loop. For example `$entity = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);`

You example code can look like that

```
$properties = $em->getClassMetadata(User::class)->getFieldNames();
$output = array_merge(
    $properties,
    $em->getClassMetadata(User::class)->getAssociationNames()
);

$entity = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);
$reflector = new \ReflectionObject($entity);
$count = 0;

foreach ($output as $property) {
    $method = $reflector->getMethod('get'.ucfirst($property));
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $result = $method->invoke($entity);
    if ($result instanceof PersistentCollection) {
        $collectionReflector = new \ReflectionObject($result);
        $method = $collectionReflector->getMethod('count');
        $method->setAccessible(true);
        $result = $method->invoke($result);
    }
    $result == null ?: $count++;
}
```

Variable `$count` will show you how many empty properties there are in the entity.

**Notice:** *This code should NOT be use in Production!*